# How to do you make the verticles to make the triangle curved?

Tags: modeling, edit-mode

[image]

Im quite new to blender and I am wondering on how to make these triangles look curved?

Comment: Select the vertices at the tip of the triangles (or the pits if you want) and press `Ctrl + Shift + B` (vertex bevel) and drag the mouse to change the size. Scroll the mouse wheel to increase/decrease the number of segments. Or you could add a _subdivision surface modifier_ to round out the mesh, but this would likely require _supporting geometry_ to give the mesh a proper shape.

Comment: Thanks! It worked as intended